# Plotting multiple rows in R

Tags: r

I have data:

```
Basal <- c(211,  365,  275,  383,  207, 1566,  385,  540,  366,  251, 
      112,  370,  245,  168,  486,  228,  231,  686,  240,  347)
Min5 <- c(25,  91,  94,  98,  46, 205, 136,  94,  95,  69,  32, 132,  49, 
     119, 154,  79,  89, 163, 218,  49)
Min10 <- c(19,  73,  60,  77,  38, 159, 125,  76,  88,  62,  21,  97,  47, 
     102, 149,  47,  62, 137, 180,  47)
Min15 <- c(17,  58,  42,  70,  33, 131,  NA,  66,  89,  58,  NA,  62,  45, 
     55, 150,  37,  55, 123, 114,  51)

Cure <- c(rep("Cure",4), rep("Pers",16))
Df <- data.frame(Basal,Min5,Min10,Min15)
```

Could you help me plot the data so that all the variables in each rows will be connected with lines (Cure - green, Pers - red)

Something like that, but I want to have 20 lines (in this case) instead of 2.

[image]

Comment: I think that variable for each **columns** are connected. You sure you want connect them by rows?

Comment: yes, I want to connect them by rows

Comment: Each row represents the intraoperative hormone changes of patients (basal - preoperative, at 5 minutes, at 10 minutes, at 15 minutes). So I want to visualize these changes.

Comment: Try with `matplot`. ie. `matplot(t(Df), type='l')`

Comment: Clear now. I thought they were different variables but in fact as you said is just one variable observed at different time intervals.

Comment: Also make some transformation for better visibility, like `log(t(Df))`.

Answer (score 3):

This delivers what was requested although I think trying to read 20 lines at once will be difficult:

```
matplot( t(Df), type="l")
```

The `matplot` function usually works on columns but transposing makes the groupings row-wise.

Regarding colors, I thought the red and green contrast was difficult to resolve in my visual system so went with green and orange:

```
matplot(t(Df), type="l", col=c( "orange", "darkgreen")[1+(Cure=="Cure")] )
```

And if you make the non-green color slightly transparent, then the green lines don't get obscured as much. Also looks a bit less garish.

```
matplot(t(Df), type="l", col=c( "#88440060", "darkgreen")[1+(Cure=="Cure")] )
```

The transparency aspect is controlled by the last two hex digits in the R color sysem where the first 6 digits are "#RRGGBB" and the final tow optional digits are alpha-transparency. See `?rgb` and `?colors` and the other pages and packages linked from there.

[image]

Comment: You get the colors using `col=ifelse(Cure=="Cure","green","red")`